# Detecting Favicon Dimensions for Responsive Favicons

Tags: javascript, favicon, responsive-design

Favicons can be rendered as any of [16x16, 32x32, 48x48, 64x64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon).

For the purposes of [dynamic favicons](http://softwareas.com/dynamic-favicons), I'm wondering if there's a way to detect favicon dimensions, or at least a reference showing which browsers are using which dimensions. Google draws a blank on that.

Comment: Prolly not helpful to the OP but I feel the idea of responsive favicons is taking it a little too far, sorry.

Comment: This is for applications like showing a badge number or the way Google Calendar shows current date. The main point is to decide whether certain dynamic displays are feasible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean to get the dimensions of the image? try something like this

```
var el = document.querySelector('link[rel="shortcut icon"],link[rel="icon"]');
var url = el.href || "/favicon.ico"
var image = new Image();
image.src = url;
image.onload = function(){
    alert(image.width + " , " + image.height);
};
```

Comment: Accepted, Probably as state-of-the-art as possible here :D.